# Eclipse Neon CDT missing manage configurations button

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I created a C project in eclipse neon and I am trying to delete some of the build configurations.  However I can not get to the manage configurations dialog I am used to.  The button seems to be missing.  Did it go somewhere else or is my eclipse just buggy?

[image]

I think this window is supposed to look more like this.  See how there is a manage configurations button next to the dropdown at the top.
[image]

I just tried switching workspaces and when I use a clean workspace I can see the button.

Comment: Interesting. I have the "Manage Configurations" button in my Neon.2 installation, just like in your second screenshot.

Comment: When I switched to another workspace the issue went away.  Something weird was happening.  I deleted the dot files in my workspace and redid my settings.  Now everything works.

Comment: This is still an issue. Currently a show stopper.

Answer (score 0):

While the aforementioned hacks indeed work, such an approach is impossible when one already has many projects and now wishes to target another architecture.

I have found another way.

Right click on the project and select, from the pop-up menu,**Build Configurations**, and one of the menu items is **Manage**. This behaves as the disappearing Manage Configurations button.

PS: this is still a problem with Oxygen 3.